# Sort with Cells not range

Tags: excel, vba

So I'm trying to sort a column in ascending order(the column will change based on a previous integer defined earlier in the code) so I don't want to use `Range("B34:B57") etc.`

Instead, I've defined the column in question earlier in the code as a variable `currentcol`, and here's what I have so far:

```
Dim firstpy As Long
Dim lastpy As Long
            
     firstpy = Cells(34, currentcol)
     lastpy = Cells(57, currentcol)
            
        Range(firstpy & lastpy).Sort Key1:=Cells(34, currentcol), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo
```

I believe the problem is in the `Key1` reference? Can someone help sort this out? :)

Comment: `Range(firstpy & lastpy)` looks off if those are two `Long` variables

Comment: They don't need to be ```Long```, what's the appropriate variable type they should be? ```Range```? @TimWilliams

Comment: Range would be a good option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Sort a One-Column Range

**A Quick Fix**

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Test()
    
    Const CurrentCol As Long = 1 ' just to make it compile
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    
    Dim firstPy As Range: Set firstPy = ws.Cells(34, CurrentCol)
    Dim lastPy As Range: Set lastPy = ws.Cells(57, CurrentCol)
    
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ws.Range(firstPy, lastPy)
    ' Or without the variables:
    'Set rg = ws.Range(ws.Cells(34, CurrentCol), ws.Cells(57, CurrentCol))
                 
    rg.Sort Key1:=rg, Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! this worked perfectly, I see where my mistake was.